# Adding a new column in SQL corresponding to previous columns (extension)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a new column in an existing SQL table (name: mytable) which when a user starts a new project within 20mins, it is consisted to be in the same "timetable"(new column).

When a new user is registered, the timetable goes back to 1.

Please see the case below:

```
Name        Date/Time
Candance    2018-09-22 11:20:14
Candance    2018-09-22 11:35:12
Candance    2018-09-22 11:50:35 
Jon         2018-09-23 12:12:13
Jon         2018-09-23 12:20:34
Jon         2018-09-23 12:40:54
Jon         2018-09-24 09:43:32
```

Output:

```
Name        Date/Time            Timetable
Candance    2018-09-22 11:20:14  1 
Candance    2018-09-22 11:35:12  1
Candance    2018-09-22 11:58:35  2
Jon         2018-09-23 12:12:13  1
Jon         2018-09-23 12:20:34  1
Jon         2019-09-23 12:35:34  1
Jon         2018-09-23 14:32:54  2
Jon         2018-09-24 09:43:32  3
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please add one more row like `'Jon' - '2018-09-23 12:35:34'`. It posesses out of 20min for first row in `timetable=1` for this user, but within 20min for last row in this timetable... what timetable value does this row must be assigned to? what is the base of needed enumeration?

Comment: Hi @Akina thanks for the response! Just cleared it up in my question. Basically when a user performs a date within 20 mins following the previous date, it is considered the same"timetable". (however when the user changes, the timetable resets to 1). Sorry if it was confusing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum.  Date/time functions vary by database but in standard SQL:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_datetime > datetime - interval '6' hour then 0 else 1 end) over
           (partition by name order by datetime) as timetable
from (select t.*,
             lag(datetime) over (partition by name order by datetime) as prev_datetime
      from t
     ) t;
```

The major issue across databases is how you subtract six hours from a date/time.